# Unable to set @Input decorators value in spec file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing test case on form submit where Input decorater(eg:station) value been reassigned while submitting form.
When I am trying to define that Input value in spec file component.station value is coming as undefined where in unable to set its value because component does not have station input value to assign value in test case.
How to get @Input station in component list in test case.
component.ts:

```
@Input station : Object;
```

spec.ts:

```
 it('should update form onsubmit', () => {
    spyOn(component.submitConfirmed, 'emit');
    jasmine.createSpy('onSubmit');
    const valueServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('OcppService', [
      'configureStation',
    ]);
    // here component does not have station field. shows error undefined component.station.
    component.station.name = 'station 02';
    component.form = form;
    const formValue = component.form.getRawValue();
    component.onSubmit();
    expect(valueServiceSpy.getValue.calls.mostRecent().returnValue).toBe(
      formValue
    );
    expect(component.submitConfirmed.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      valid: true,
      station: component.station,
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing parenthesis after Input

```
@Input() station: string;
```

Also after changing the station value add, to update the template

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Check if this works